# Why do I receive a "/bin/bash cannot find command" error for an alias?

Tags: bash, vim, python

I am using multiple python, I alias `python3` to `py`:

```
alias py="/opt/python3.4/bin/python3"
```

I want to run python in `vim` so I write this:

```
map <F9> :call SpecialCompileRun()<CR>
func! SpecialCompileRun()
    exec "w"
    if &filetype == 'python'
        exec '!time py %'                                                                                                                                                                               
    endif
endfunc
```

but when I press `F9` in vim, it tells me that:

`/bin/bash py cannot find command`

when I change `py` to `python3`, it is ok now, but I still want to know why?

Answer (score 11):

Because the way you define it `py` is a shell alias, and Vim doesn't know (nor care) about shell aliases.  Use an environment variable instead, perhaps like this:

```sh
$ PY=/opt/python3.4/bin/python3
$ export PY
```

then in Vim:

```
...
exec '!time ' . fnameescape($PY) . ' %'
...
```

**Edit:**  Added `fnameescape()`.  It's needed if `$PY` contains characters that have a special meaning to Vim (f.i. `#` and `%`).

Comment: `!` spawns a shell though. However that shell is non-interactive so doesn't read customisation files like `~/.bashrc` and in the case of `bash` doesn't expand aliases anyway.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: Did you look at Vim's sources?  It's a lot more complicated than that, `!` may or may not spawn a shell.  Try this: add `alias foo=ls` to a file, set `BASH_ENV` to point to it (assuming your login shell is `bash`...), then open a file in Vim and run `!foo`.

Comment: As I said, non-interactive bash don't expand aliases. You'd need to add a `shopt -s expand_aliases` to your BASH_ENV file. (you also need `SHELL=/bin/bash`, as vim runs the shell mentioned in there).

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas: Since we're nitpicking: if `SHELL` is missing, Vim sets its option `shell` to your login shell.  But, you're right, adding `shopt -s expand_aliases` to the `BASH_ENV` file makes it work.  Whatever.

Answer (score 5):

As @lcd047 told you, aliases are not available to `vim`. They are also, by the way, not available to shell scripts either, unless you activate the `expand_aliases` option.

Anyway, another choice would be to create a link instead of an alias:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/python3.4/bin/python3 /usr/bin/py
```

That will create a link at `/usr/bin/py` which points to `/opt/python3.4/bin/python3`. Since `/usr/bin` is in your `$PATH`, the `py` command will be available everywhere.

Comment: I would go for the link approach, but in some user-writeable directory in the PATH rather than in /usr/bin. Least privilege, and all that.

Comment: Actually, an environment variable might still be better if you want to do things like switch between Python2 and Python3. _shrug_

Comment: @Score_Under true, but that would (of course) only be for one user, which may or may not be what the OP wants, and not all systems have a user-writeable directory in the default `PATH`. Some include `~/bin` if present but others don't.